# One-way repeated measures ANOVA and missing data

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, missing-data

I have following data for the one-way repeated measures ANOVA test and I don't know how to deal with missing values.

The data looks something like this:

```
users  | type 1 | type 2 | type 3 | type 4 | type 5

user 1 |    x   |    x   |    -   |    -   |   x
user 2 |    x   |    x   |    x   |    -   |   -
user 3 |    x   |    x   |    x   |    x   |   -
user 4 |    x   |    x   |    -   |    x   |   x
...
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It might help to get a little more information. Is your response variable continuous? Are the 'types' ordered in time?

Comment: Oh, of course! The types are different tasks and the values are times. x = several time values (unfortunately different amount of values for each x)

Comment: What are you measuring, *exactly*, and what is your research question (e.g., response time as a function of task type) and your operational hypothesis?

Comment: Ok, I have several response times per user and per task. In the end I want to prove that users perform task 1 significantly quicker or slower than task 2. And the same for the other tasks.